# How to find and replace a string in %PATH% system variable with variables in a batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line, system-variable, delayedvariableexpansion

I am trying to upgrade Java with a batch file, and I need to change the PATH system variable to reflect that change. At the beginning of the PATH variable I have

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51;...
```

I need to change the jdk value to be jdk1.8.0_60. I'm relatively new to command line and batch files, and so I may be misunderstanding something. Here is what I am trying.

I have a couple variables

```
jVersion=1.8.0_
javaPath=C:\Program Files\Java
newVersion=60
oldVersion=51
```

I found something about replacing strings with literal values like so

```
set PATH=%PATH:1.8.0_51=1.8.0_60%
```

but I can't get it to work with variables...

```
set PATH=%%PATH:%jVersion%%oldVersion%=%jVersion%%newVersion%%%
```

I don't know if you need 2 %'s around the outside, or just one, or !'s. I'm not super confident in my knowledge of delayed expansion. I also don't know if this is possible.

As a bonus, I would really like to be able to take whatever comes after ...\Java\ and replace it with my new value. This would be just in case I don't know the value in the PATH variable for the jdk

Thanks!

**EDIT**: 
By using the command `call` before a modified version of my code I was able to get it to work

```
call set PATH=%PATH:%jVersion%%oldVersion%=%jVersion%%newVersion%%
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to make it generic and change whatever comes after `...\jdk` to the values I have.

Comment: Try to prepend `call` to your last line of code...

Comment: Enable delayed variable expansion, then use immediate `%%` expansion for the find/replace strings and delayed `!!` expansion for the whole expression;

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl that worked!

Comment: the `call` worked when I removed one of my outer `%`. Using `!` on the outside instead of `%` did not work

Comment: Ok the `!` method did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste the Below Code in a bat file and that should solve the problem

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set jVersion=1.8.0_
set "javaPath=C:\Program Files\Java"
set newVersion=60
set oldVersion=51
set PATH=%jVersion%%oldVersion%
echo before path change : !PATH!
set PATH=!PATH:%jVersion%%oldVersion%=%jVersion%%newVersion%!
echo final path change  : !PATH!
pause
```

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks! Using call and a single `%` on either side works as well

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you want to do but might solve the problem. 
Create a new environment variable called `JAVA_HOME` and let it point to your java installation folder. From now on manipulate this `JAVA_HOME` variable instead. You can replace it every time with your script.
Edit your `PATH` environment variable (only once) so that it includes this new `JAVA_HOME` variable like this `PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60;%PATH%
```

if you put the new JDK in the path *before* the current one, the OS will use the new JDK.

But you would be far better off editing your `PATH` system setting and *replacing* the old JDK path with the *new* old.

Comment: Yeah this would work, but would increase the size of the path unnecessarily after time. I agree replacing it would be better. Thanks